# GraphQL client not reading certain query variables

Tags: graphql, graphql-playground

I have a database that consists of the following 3 entries:

```
{
  "username": "negger",
  "firstName": "Arnold"
},
{
  "username": "jonsnow",
  "firstName": "Jon"
},
{
  "username": "tonystark",
  "firstName": "Tony"
}
```

In my GraphQL Playground (https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql), you can run the following query:

```
{
  users (where: {username: "jonsnow"}) {
    username
    firstName
  }
}
```

And it'll return the matching data as you'd expect:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "username": "jonsnow",
        "firstName": "Jon"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, if you try using query variables in order to dynamically lookup entries by `username`, the `where` clause is simply ignored! Here's the dynamic query I'm running:

```
query users($username: String!) {
  users(where: {username: $username}) {
    username
    firstName
  }
}
```

And here's the query variable definition:

```
{
  "username": "jonsnow"
}
```

[image]

My question is, what sorcery is this? Why wouldn't the playground client respect query variables even when the value being passed exists!

Comment: Hm I just tried the same query syntax in GraphiQL client which is very similar and it worked fine

Comment: This is so frustrating. I've been stuck with this for almost 2 weeks now and have no clue what I'm doing wrong! Did you try the second method, i.e. with query variables? And it returned only the matching entry?

Comment: Yes I used query + variable `query teams($bpxId:Long) {
  teams(filter: {bpxId:{eq: $bpxId}}) {
   name
  }
}` - different query of course but same idea of plugging a var in

Comment: Can you please try the query I've posted over at https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, most certainly an issue on the server side implementation as two requests aren't equal when sending a query as opposed to something static as nothing wrong with what you're putting in on the UI